# Symfony2 multiple Entities of same class in one Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to render a form which has multiple Entities of same Class.
I will display 2 fields, Price(type=text) and Enabled(type=checkbox).

I don't know how many I will have of those entities, so form will have to get them dynamically.

I have tried to do the following

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

        $builder
            ->add('price', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Price',
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('enabled','checkbox',array(
                'label'     => 'Use this currency',

            ))
        ;    
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'Osiris\Entity\Pricing',
        'csrf_protection'   => false
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'pricingtype';
}
```

And in my Controller I have created my form like this:

```
$pricingForm = $this->createFormBuilder($prices)
               ->add('items','collection',array(
                   'required' => false,
                   'prototype' => true,
                   'type'    => new PricingType(),
               ))
                ->getForm()
            ;
```

In my twig I do:

```
{% for price in form_pricing %}
    <h2>Price</h2>
    <div class="row">{{ form_widget(price) }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However it comes only with h2 Prices and empty div with class=row. I feel like I am half way there, but I've no idea how to move on.
If someone knows how to get fields on submit as well, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: you got the solution you were looking for?

Comment: Yes I posted it as an answer to my question below.

Answer (score 2):

**I found the solution**,

the way I was creating the form in Controller was wrong!
I had to do the following:

```
$pricingForm = $this->createFormBuilder(array('prices'=>$prices))
                ->add('prices','collection',array(
                    'required'       => true,
                    'allow_add'      => true,
                    'type'           => new PricingType(),
               ))
                ->getForm()
            ;
```

"allow_add => true" is necessary when working with collection, otherwise it will **NOT** add any of PricingType collection of entities to the form.

Then, because the form is built inside the controller "`$this->createFormBuilder(array('prices'=>$prices))`" , `$prices` array must be passed as an array with array keyname same as the one used in "`->add('prices','collection',array(...)`" , which is `'prices'` so Symfony will know what to bind where. `$prices` is an array of Pricing objects `array(0 => new Pricing())`.

In my PricingType I have:

```
class PricingType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('price', 'text', array(
                'label' => false,
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('enabled','checkbox',array(
                'label'     => 'Use this currency',

            ))
        ;

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'        =>  'XXX\XXX\Entity\Pricing',
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pricingtype';
    }
}
```

Here I need to have control over label attribute. I could not find the way for it( if anyone knows please post how to). I override my twig template as follows:

On the top we need next line of code:

```
    {% form_theme form_pricing _self %}
```

Then  override row and widget as follows (it was a nightmare to debug):

```
{% block _form_prices_entry_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block _form_prices_entry_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}

        {{ form_row(form.price, { 'label' : form.vars.value.getCurrency().getTitle() } ) }}
        {{ form_row(form.enabled) }}

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the body then, render form elements as follows:

```
{% for price in form_pricing.prices %}
                    <div class="price-row">{{ form_row(price) }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
```

I really hope this will help you guyz. It was a real nightmare to debug especially the twig file, I did it thanks to my clever colleague.

Comment: Hi, This is exactly what I trying to do, but I am not able to clone your solution. How do you define your controllers? If you are still on it, please explain to me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a **for loop** in your twig file
Check this example:

```
    {# store the prototype on the data-prototype attribute #}
    <ul id="email-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.emails.vars.prototype)|e }}">
    {% for emailField in form.emails %}
        <li>
            {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
            {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

See the loop, I think that you need to add in your twig file.

In addition to loops you need to add **JavaScript** also.

Check this link:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items

Check the complete code. It will help you out to generate multiple entity forms from a single entity class using collection field type.

Comment: It is a nice example, but I don't give option to user to add more fields to that form.

Comment: then don't add JavaScript code, just form and twig code is enough.

Comment: I create an array of Pricing and pass it to FormBuilder. When I loop over my form in twig ( 
{% for price in form_pricing.prices %} 
<div class="row">{{ form_widget(price) }}</div>
) 
It does not render anything back. Any idea?

Comment: From Symfony2 Example Page: In both cases, no input fields would render unless your emails data array already contained some emails. given in this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage