# How to accept table-like data in Symfony 3 Form Component

Tags: php, symfony

I want to achieve a form using Symfony's form component that will allow the submission of rows of related data. Each row will contain individual fields that are related to the other fields in that row.

The resultant HTML would look something like

```
<div class="row-group">
   <input type="text" name="somefield[]"/>
   <input type="text" name="someotherfield[]"/>
   <input type="text" name="somemorefield[]"/>
</div>
<div class="row-group">
   <input type="text" name="somefield[]"/>
   <input type="text" name="someotherfield[]"/>
   <input type="text" name="somemorefield[]"/>
</div>
```

My current strategy is to create a custom field type similar to the DateTimeType in Symfony and then add multiples of that to a CollectionType.

However I notice on submission the DateTimeType concatenates the day/month/year + time parts into one string, which isn't what I want.

It seems as though there should be an easier way to accomplish this without creating custom types.

Comment: Did you intend to have two div elements with exactly the same `name` elements in both divs? Or maybe you mean `somefield1` and `somefield2`.. or something like that. I have some suggestions, but I just want to verify.

Comment: Thanks @AlvinBunk I did intend it, but only to feed them all into an array, but I've managed to get somewhat of a solution working that follows a structure of name="form[field][0][field_fragment]" that is generated by Symfony using a combination of a custom FormType and CollectionType. About to post my solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this doing essentially what I said in the question, using a custom FormType extended from AbstractType and a CollectionType, in the end it was not much work but it was definitely not an intuitive process.

First, create the Custom Form Type by extending AbstractType and specifying FormType as the parent, this is necessary because our Custom Type will use multiple fields:

```
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('one', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('two', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('three', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }
}
```

A form fragment will then be needed for the new custom type:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block my_custom_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% for child in form %}
            <div>
                {{ form_widget(child) }}
                {{ form_label(child) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

This will loop through all of the items 'one', 'two', 'three' created in the builder.

Then, create a form that uses a CollectionType to list multiples of your MyCustomType:

```
class MyForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('testing', CollectionType::class,
            array(
                'entry_type' => MyCustomType::class,
                'allow_add' => true
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, create the form. You will need to load the data in using the second param of the createForm() method to get the fields to show. If you don't have initial data, then you will need to modify this to show a blank MyCustomType to begin with:

(Thanks to this question for this: [Symfony2 multiple Entities of same class in one Form (SOLVED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371638/symfony2-multiple-entities-of-same-class-in-one-form-solved))

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(MyForm::class, array('testing' => array(
        array('one' => 'hello', 'two' => 'hi', 'three' => 'goodbye'),
        array('one' => 'hello', 'two' => 'hi', 'three' => 'goodbye')
    )));

    if($form->handleRequest($request))
    {
        $result = $form->getData();
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'result' => print_r($result, true));
}
```

The submitted data will look like this:

```
Array ( [testing] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [one] => [two] => hi123 [three] => goodbye123 ) [1] => Array ( [one] => [two] => hi [three] => goodbye ) ) )
```

If you want to concatenate or do something else with the data instead, you can use a Data Transformer to do that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

Toby, regarding your DateTimeType questions (in your question you actually have multiple questions), you could use the [DateType Field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) instead.

In one of my forms I have a date of birth field, and here is a sample:

```
->add('dob', null, array(
        'format' => 'dd MMM y',
        'label' => 'Birthdate:',
        'years' => range(2000,1960,1),
))
```

I checked in MySQL, and it uses `date` type, and the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. So that might help you with that part of your question(s).